# sqlite3_open allocates memory that isn't being released by sqlite3_close

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, sqlite

sqlite3_open allocates memory that isn't being released by sqlite3_close
I have the following code:

```
sqlite3* db = nil;    
const char* path = "...\myDb.sqlitedb";
//print memory usage
int error = sqlite3_open(path,&db);
//print memory usage
sqlite3_close(db);
//print memory usage
free(db);
//print memory usage
```

According to the prints of the memory usage - i see that the open allocates arround 50KB 
and the close and free doesn't release this memory.

Anyone has an idea why? how should i release this memory? i'm using alot of sql queries in my app - and i can't afford this leaks...
the entire function is wrapped arround an autoreleasepool block - so  i don't think that is what causing the problem.

Any ideas? 
I'm desperate! :(

Comment: Calling `free(db)` will corrupt memory. Does the memory continue to increase when you are calling open/close in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on the workings of this line here:

```
//print memory usage
```

which you haven't specified in a great amount of detail :-).

It's quite possible that you're reporting memory usage wrongly.

For example, if you're simply reporting how much memory the process has allocated from the OS, it's likely that this may increase when opening the database but not decrease when closing it, because *it's not handed back to the OS.* Memory allocation functions don't tend to hand it back, on the assumption they'll probably need it again.

In any case, your leak (even if it exists) is not that serious unless you're opening and closing databases a lot, something you may want to avoid since it will have a performance impact as well. If you can, you should open the database once, use it a lot, then close it down once. That's the ideal use case.